# Why is it saving a state variable looks like one render behind whenever I update a state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-state

I am very new to Reactjs.
I was practising passing value from children to parent components. The practice problem is - to pass the value from the select HTML tag to the parent component. I could pass the value of the select tag using a callback function and save the value in a state variable. But while printing the state variable gives me always the previous value, not the updated one.

Here is the code -
**child component**

```
import React from 'react'

function child(props) {
    const handleChange = (e) => {
        props.value(e.currentTarget.value);
    }
    return (
         <div className='side-panel'>
            <select name="gender" id="gender" onChange={handleChange}>
                <option value="female">female</option>
                <option value="male">male</option>
                <option value="others">others</option>
            </select>
            </div>
    )
}

export default Sidebar
```

**parent component**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import Child from './Child';

function Parent() {
    const [val, setVal] = useState('what from parent');
    return (
        <div className='layout'>
            <Child value={(gender) => {
                setVal(gender);
                console.log(`from food ` + val);
            }}/>
           
        </div>
    )
}

export default Parent
```

In the parent component, printing val state always gives previous value. Isn't it supposed to give me an updated value of val state? Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 3):

### **It's because [Reactjs's update batching](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous) mechanism**

**Meaning that state update is asynchronous**

When updating state within an eventHandler like onChange, onClick,.etc.., React will batch all of setState into one:

As a result, you will not see the last updated value in your `console.log()` if you place it in the same function/event handler.

---

**In your example, `setState` will cause a re-render, so if you want to see your updated state**

Place a log right before the `return` statement like so:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import Child from './Child';

function Parent() {
    const [val, setVal] = useState('what from parent');
    console.log(`from food ` + val);
    return (
        <div className='layout'>
            <Child value={(gender) => {
                setVal(gender);
            }}/>
           
        </div>
    )
}

export default Parent
```

Comment: Thanks for the direction. checking the value using console.log in an event handler was a wrong debugging approach.